# Passing variable to window.open

Tags: javascript

I have just encountered an error - I cannot access passed object in the dialog window in Internet Explorer 11. It works in Firefox and Chrome. What did Microsoft changed? As far as I remember it worked in previous versions?

```
var obj = {
wnd: window.open("/" + project + "/magic/dialog-timepair.html", "cellValue", "width=450,height=150"),
};
obj.wnd.cell = {sTime: 'x', eTime: 'y'};
```

Comment: Look for console error .. will help you find the current issue

Comment: you could also try the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's more standard for the child window to *pull* a value from the parent window, as opposed to the parent window *pushing* a value to the child window.  You can use `window.opener` in the child window to reference the parent window.  So in the parent you might have something like this:

```
window.open("/" + project + "/magic/dialog-timepair.html", "cellValue", "width=450,height=150");

// ...

function getCell() {
    return {sTime: 'x', eTime: 'y'};
}
```

Then in the child window's page, when you need these values, you'd call:

```
var cell = window.opener.getCell();
```